# Why do we need to convert to dart object when getting data from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to programming and this is something simple yet i'm kind of confused.

```
                                email: _emailController.text.trim(),
                                password: _passController.text.trim(),
                              );
                              await _firestore
                                  .collection("users")
                                  .doc("${user.user?.uid}")
                                  .set({
                                "username": _usernameController.text.trim(),
                                "email": _emailController.text.trim()
                              });
```

So in this code, i'm sending username and email to the firebase firestore, it'll create the collection "users" and document "uid" if there's not one presenet already and with a Map username: username and email: email, So this is working as it should. But here i did not create a model class to send the Data to the firestore But in case of getting the data.

```
    _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_auth.currentUser?.uid)
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        user = documentSnapshot.data();
      } else {
        print("Data doesn't exist");
      }
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

why do i have to convert the documentSnapshot.data(); into a dart object creating a model class?
This is something really simple yet i can't understand it properly and would like for someone to help me a bit?
Thank you.

Comment: I personally think your question might go further than just Flutter. We model data because we find important to Engineer it. Best practices like these have a variety of important implications that it's impossible to write them all in this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best explanation is probably in the [cloud_firestore 2.x migration guide](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/2.0.0_migration).

As shown there you don't necessarily have to create a model class, but you'll aways have to indicate what type of data is in a `DocumentSnapshot`. If you don't have a model class, you can just use `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Comment: Thank you! 
        ```.get()((DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        user = documentSnapshot.data();```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of creating a model class is to make things simpler and keep things in order. it's not mandatory to create it but it makes it a lot easier to use that response and work with it.